# Different methods on a single button based on the group of the user? odoo 12

Tags: odoo

I've created a button and wrote a certain function in its method,So now i have to implement like if the user in the certain group click the button i need to trigger a `wizard`.(i have to take a user input and continue).

And also please let me know is there any other type of `TransientModel` in odoo 12 other than wizard like a `message prompt` where we can take the user input and continue?

Answer (score 2):

You can add multiple versions of the button. I mean you can add multiple buttons with the same 'display name', i.e, string attribute, which will each one call a different method, and show it based on the user group by adding attribute 'groups' in the button and giving the particular group you want it to be visible for

Example:

```
<button name="method_1" string="MyButton" groups="sale.group_sale_salesman" type="object"/>
<button name="method_2" string="MyButton" groups="stock.group_stock_user" type="object"/>
```

Comment: Good answer, adding a simple example would make it even better :-P